# Can't Return JSON object using MongoEngine Pymongo with Django?

Tags: django, json, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

So I'm trying to return a JSON object for a project.  I've spent a few hours trying to get Django just returning the JSON.

Heres the view that we've been working with:

```
def json(request, first_name):
    user = User.objects.all()
    #user = User.objects.all().values()
    result = simplejson.dumps(user, default=json_util.default)
    return HttpResponse(result)
```

Here's my model:

```
class User(Document):  
    gender = StringField( choices=['male', 'female', 'Unknown']) 
    age = IntField()
    email = EmailField()
    display_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    location = StringField(max_length=50)
    status = StringField(max_length=50)
    hideStatus = BooleanField()
    photos = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Photo')) 
    profile =ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('ProfileItem'))
    allProfile = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('ProfileItem')) #only return for your own profile
```

This is what it's returning:

```
[<User: User object>, <User: User object>] is not JSON serializable
```

Any thoughts on how I can just return the JSON?

Answer (score 11):

With MongoEngine 0.8 or greater, objects and querysets have a `to_json()` method.

```
>>> User.objects.to_json()
```

Answer (score 8):

`simplejson.dumps()` doesn't know how to "reach into" your custom objects; the `default` function, `json_util.default` must just be calling `str()` or `repr()` on your documents. (Is `json_util` custom code you've written? If so, showing its source here could prove my claim.)

Ultimately, your `default` function will need to be able to make sense of the MongoEngine documents. I can think of at least two ways that this might be implemented:

1. Write a custom `default` function that works for all MongoEngine documents by introspecting their `_fields` attribute (though note that the leading underscore means that this is part of the private API/implementation detail of MongoEngine and may be subject to change in future versions)
2. Have each of your documents implement a `as_dict` method which returns a dictionary representation of the object. This would work similarly to the `to_mongo` method provided on documents by MongoEngine, but shouldn't return the `_types` or `_cls` fields (again, these are implementation details of MongoEngine).

I'd suggest you go with option #2: the code will be cleaner and easier to read, better encapsulated, and won't require using any private APIs.

Answer (score 4):

As dcrosta suggested you can do something like this, hope that will help you.

**Document definition**

```
class MyDocument(Document):
    # Your document definition

    def to_dict(self):
        return mongo_to_dict_helper(self)
```

**helper.py:**

```
from mongoengine import StringField, ListField, IntField, FloatField

def mongo_to_dict_helper(obj):
    return_data = []
    for field_name in obj._fields:
        if field_name in ("id",):
            continue

        data = obj._data[field_name]

        if isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], StringField):
            return_data.append((field_name, str(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], FloatField):
            return_data.append((field_name, float(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], IntField):
            return_data.append((field_name, int(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], ListField):
            return_data.append((field_name, data))
        else:
            # You can define your logic for returning elements
    return dict(return_data)
```