# Flask Jsonify mongoengine query

Tags: python, json, flask, mongoengine, simplejson

I have method like this , and want to return as Json , but it writes that Posts object is not Json serializable :S

```
def show_results_async(text):
   query  =  { '$or':[{'title':{'$regex':text}},{'author':{'$regex':text}} ]}
   posts = Posts.objects(__raw__=(query))
   return jsonify(result = posts)
```

Comment: why is it `__raw__=(query)`? did you mean `__raw__=(query,)` or `__raw__=query`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tl,dr: There is no built-in function that'll convert a MongoEngine document to JSON. So you'll need to write your own.

In views.py:

```
def show_results_async(text):
   query  =  { '$or':[{'title':{'$regex':text}},{'author':{'$regex':text}} ]}
   posts = Posts.objects(__raw__=(query))
   return jsonify(result=posts.to_dict())
```

In post.py, add:

```
def to_dict(self):
   return helper.mongo_to_dict(self)
```

In helper.py:

```
def mongo_to_dict(obj):
    return_data = []

    if isinstance(obj, Document):
        return_data.append(("id",str(obj.id)))

    for field_name in obj._fields:

        if field_name in ("id",):
            continue

        data = obj._data[field_name]

        if isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], DateTimeField):
            return_data.append((field_name, str(data.isoformat())))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], StringField):
            return_data.append((field_name, str(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], FloatField):
            return_data.append((field_name, float(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], IntField):
            return_data.append((field_name, int(data)))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], ListField):
            return_data.append((field_name, data))
        elif isinstance(obj._fields[field_name], EmbeddedDocumentField):
            return_data.append((field_name, mongo_to_dict(data)))

    return dict(return_data)
```

A couple of notes:

- If your document has additional field types, you need to enhance the helper function above.
- The helper method above was inspired by [Thomas' answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206391/153945). Additional functionality includes: recursively print out EmbeddedDocuments and include the id of the document.

Comment: `my_document.to_json()` converts a MongoEngine document to JSON. It doesn't work to `jsonify()` that JSON though. I used `json.loads()` to convert it to a dict and then `return jsonify()` it, though there is probably a better way.

Answer (score 12):

You can use mongoengine built-in method : to_json(). Example above that , you can use like this:

```
def show_results_async(text):
   query  =  { '$or':[{'title':{'$regex':text}},{'author':{'$regex':text}} ]}
   posts = Posts.objects(__raw__=(query))
   return jsonify(result = posts.to_json())
```

Comment: Doesn't that backslash-escape quotes, since it's double json-ified? I needed to do something like `jsonify(result=[json.loads(post.to_json()) for post in Posts.objects])`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, though I don't know if it's the most efficient way:

```
import json

@app.route('/api/my-objects/')
def get_objects():
    all_objects = [json.loads(o.to_json()) for o in MyObject.objects]

    return jsonify({"my_objects": all_objects})
```